# How to get 3D point using 2D screen location in javafx?

Tags: java, javafx, 3d, point

I am creating 3D application using Javafx in which I wanted to find the location of 3D point in node corresponds to 2D point present on Screen.

In this application, I am adding subscene to show 3D view. Now I wanted add one more 3D object into same subscene but 3D coordinates for that object should be specific location of subscene/screen and XY plane of my current 3D view.

[Application Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXp8w.png)

Please let me know if there is any way to get 3D point using 2D screen coordinates.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: You would need at least two 2D Points from different angle to reconstruct a 3D Point.

Comment: @Fildor No, since additionally a node is involved: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24211/graphics3d-finding-intersection-of-3d-objects-and-lines

Comment: @fabian oops, overread that node ...

Comment: @fabian: I just updated my question and I need JavaFX8 APIs which can give me point in 3D view.